# Why did he multiplied with the emitter current?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I don't understand why did he multiplied in that equation with the Emitter current (1.618, calculated above), why would it be the same in the collector?

Answer (score 2):

For amplifiers there are design equations and analysis equations.  The design equations are slightly simplified, in order to make the process of picking parts and currents easier.
Then once you have a first order design done, you go back and use the analysis equations to make sure you have met all the design goals and tweak as needed.

For first order design equations, Ie = Ic.
For analysis equations Ie = Ic + Ib.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A normal jellybean BJT typically has an hFE of the order of several hundred, so we can ignore base current to a first approximation. The resistors and power supply will likely be 1% or 5% tolerance, for example, so 0.3% (in this case 0.67%) doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest error actually is the assumption for Vbe of Q1 = 700 mV which at Ic= 1.7mA is going to be < 650 mV or closer to 600mV.

So with 50 to 100mV more voltage on the emitter current factored by Rc/Re=5.3 gain means the collector will drop up to 530 mV more from this 4.176V estimate or a ~14% error from the old assumption to assume 0.7V  The datasheet will tell otherwise and is more commonly used for 10 to 20mA.

Since 0.7V is only 1 "SigFig" (significant figure),  it only makes sense to use 2 sigfigs ,max for your estimates and expect > 100/700mV= 14 % Error.

I computed Vc = 3.6V instead of 4.1

Also, 25% of any AC input is loaded down so the net AC gain of 5.3 is only 0.75*5.3= **4**

This may be marginally improved with this config but is limited due to the 600 In and 470 Out reduction in resistance.

Comment: I decided to show  you exactly https://tinyurl.com/y7pkb7mo to prove why this is more important.   Ic vs Ie is < 1% difference and does not affect the result, Nor does hFE   matter much. for DC. Got it?  It is more sensitive to voltage errors than current from Ib

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're OK up to the point where you ask the question, "why would the current in the emitter be the same in the collector?" That is, the base is 1.8V, the emitter is 1.1V (approximately), and \$I_E=1.618\text{ mA}\$.

To answer your question: the current in the emitter is not the same as the current in the collector, but it is really really close - so it is approximately the same.

Here are the details. The first transistor's \$\beta=150\$, so we can do the following calculaton:

$$
I_E=I_B+I_C\\
I_C=\beta I_B\\
I_E=(\beta + 1)I_B\\
I_C=\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}I_E\\
I_C=\frac{150}{151}I_E\\
I_C=0.993\times I_E\\
I_C\approx I_E
$$

That's why they just said \$I_C\approx I_E\$ in the derivation.